# How does <remove-project> work in repo manifest?

Tags: android, python, git, android-source, repo

I've been using `repo` for quiet a long time now but never bothered to know what `<remove-project>` in `manifest.xml` does.

What does `<remove-project>` do — it **doesn't download** the project at all or it **downloads it** but removes it from codebase later?

It's [here](https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo/+/v1.12.37/manifest_xml.py) somewhere but I'm pretty bad at reading python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md#Element-remove_project

## Element remove-project

> Deletes the named project from the internal manifest table, possibly allowing a subsequent project element in the same manifest file to replace the project with a different source.
>
> This element is mostly useful in a local manifest file, where the user can remove a project, and possibly replace it with their own definition.